# Where can I find the detail specifications of android virtual device or android emulator?

Tags: android, operating-system

I am trying to port an simple operating system for teaching to android virtual device. The final goal is to boot the OS and make some basic hardware, including the character output and touch screen, work. In order to do that I need some details information about the "hardware" of the AVD, like where the bootloader will be load in RAM and how to use the character output.  I have search over the Internet for a while and find little useful information. Can you tell where I can find the needed info or what site I should check? Thx :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is the downloadable detailed link for

[android kernel](http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html)
and
also [source code](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)

Try to go through the source code in that you can find where the whole operation starts and works.

Comment: Thx for the answer:)I've already downloaded the android source code and get quite confused. It seems that whole source contains drivers for all kinds of android devices and the target is determined by building args...I am looking for a easier way than go through the source code since what I am trying to do is much simpler than what android system can do.

Answer (score 0):

```
emulator - android = qemu
```

If you are not using android you don't need AVDs.
Check [qemu home page](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) to ontain more info.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I also what to use the "hardware" of AVD, for example, using mouse to interact with the virtual machine like using a touch screen. I hope there be a home page for android emulator like that one for qemu...